# How is my plan for an outdoor car charger and outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I want to run a cable underground to provide power to a 240V/40A car charger and a duplex 120V outlet. Looking for comments, suggestions, improvements. Haven't seen other projects like this posted here.

In further detail, I intend to run about 20 feet indoors from the panel through the brick wall of the house, and about 70 feet to the end of the driveway. I would put a subpanel there, with two breakers:

1. 15/20 A for a pair of duplex outlets: one a separate, underground connection a further 25 feet to a duplex outlet in the garden, and the other collocated with the
2. 40 A breaker for the car charger

I guess it would look roughly like this.

```
                                               2" conduit
House panel---romex---wall---LB===conduit&thwn===sweep===70foot===sweep===subpanel

            /---40A charger outlet
subpanel---|                                   1" conduit
            \---15A duplex outlet===sweep===25foot===sweep===15A duplex outlet
```

I'll rent a ditch witch to get deep enough that the top of my conduit is at least 18" down. Having pulled some wire through conduit before, I'm kind of willing to go to 2" (it's schedule 40 PVC, over double the price of 1"), trading some money for reduced misery. While assembling the conduit I'll pull twine, so that once it's in the ground I can use it to pull 3x#6 THWN-2 CU and 1x#8 THWN-2 CU ground, for the house-to-subpanel wiring.

So my questions include...

- Is there anything stupid here, or that I could improve on?
- Am I unnecessarily wasting money on the conduit or something? Not a huge fan of aluminum wiring but at least it would make my giant conduit seem less stupid. I'm not sure how much greasing up the wire helps. Conduit fill table says I need at least 3/4" schedule 40, but no way can I pull such long wire 70 feet.
- How do I terminate the big conduit at either end? Coring a 2" hole in the house will suck, and standard 3R panel boxes don't have knockouts big enough for 2" conduit. Or should I just use smaller, so that things fit more easily?
- Can I have this inspected in stages? I would prefer to do it in two steps. First the outdoor work: dig the trench, conduit, and pull the wire, and have a rough-in inspection signed off so I can fill the trench. The second step would have me drill the hole in the house, run wiring inside, and connect up the ends, and call for a final. Can I break the job up that way?

Any and all comments will probably be helpful; thank you very much in advance.

Comment: For the ignorant like me, LB=?

Comment: @Huesmann a very standard "conduit body" where the conduit enters at one end and makes an "L" by going out the **B**ack. There are other ones that go left, or right, or straight through, or make a Tee.

Comment: @Ecnerwal except in this case there doesn't appear to be any conduit entering, so I assume some sort of clamp or bushing would be used on the entry?

Comment: LB would have a conduit to the underground and a conduit through the wall to a box inside the house where the transition to cable (if used, ugh) or different conduit type (yay!) happens.

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions at once here. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to narrow scope to one question.

Comment: Pulling through conduit is the standard recommendation 'round these parts. Direct burial cable will save you some money in the short run, but will be a pain in the future should you ever need to upgrade or someone digs through the direct buried cable.

Comment: Are you sure you need a 40A car charger? You need to drive 200 miles a day to need that, or have a fairly narrow time period in your time-of-use power tariff.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Barely - figured a 40A charger gives me some flexibility for the future - like the dual charger I have my eye on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are installing conduit, remove **cable** from your thoughts - it just screws you over in multiple ways .vs. using conduit to run **wires.** So your sketch is right but your opening statement is confusing on that point.

#6 copper is insanity (a waste of considerable money for a large feeder.) Use #4 aluminum. Strongly consider using more conduit so you are just running wires in conduit all the way from your panel, rather than limiting your install by using Romex (60°C limit) at all. Conduit will let you use the 75°C column of the ampacity table. "Smurf tube" (ENT)  or Flexible Metal (FMC) is very easy to run in the house.

The main issue with "fear of aluminum wires" was that the importance of proper torque when connecting (copper or aluminum) was not understood well "back in the day" and there with not very good 15/20A device connector designs (and a bad alloy for #10/12 Ga aluminum wiring) that failed easily. Larger connectors (such as those on breakers) are alumunum, so they are actually more compatible with aluminum wiring than copper. In any case, use a torque screwdriver or torque wrench to correctly torque the fasteners to spec. If your car charger "requires copper" (some instruct that) that only needs to be the foot or so from the 40A breaker to the car charger, and it still needs to be torqued correctly.

If you own a vacuum cleaner it's *very easy* to assemble the conduit and suck twine through it with the vacuum cleaner, rather than trying to not glue twine into the joints while assembling around twine. Actually, hollow-braided ROPE (usually yellow polypropylene) is a better choice for a large pull - you can expand it over the end of the wire bundle (it's its own "cable grip") and it's less prone to cut your conduit bends than small twine, and easier on the hands.

You need schedule 80 conduit (which you'll have to visit an actual electrical supply to find, at least here the big boxes don't stock any) where the conduit is considered "exposed to damage" (typically where it comes above ground, and 18" below ground.)

1-1/4" PVC (calculated for the thicker wall schedule-80 since some of it has to be that) is plenty big for the pull to be easy at 22% fill. 1" ENT  or FMC will fit inside the house, but 1-1/4 would be more generous. 70 feet is not a long pull - don't try to do it alone, you at least want a person feeding wires in and one pulling at the far end. Also, use large radius sweeps, not the tiny bends big boxes stock - again, electrical supply (or, you and straight PVC and a heater and some care.)

The trench has to be filled before the wires are pulled in the conduit. Remember to buy "buried electric line below" warning tape. Since it usually comes in a huge roll, I suggest a strip 6" above the conduit and one 6" below ground level. If only using one, it's the 6" below ground level (you want the next idiot to find it *before* they hook the conduit/cable with their backhoe bucket.)

Your 15-or-20A 120V outlets can be on a breaker each "for free" (really the cost of the second breaker) since you have a 240V feed to the subpanel, so there's no additional loading from putting a 120V outlet on one phase, or two on two phases.

Since you have a subpanel, you'll need a local grounding rod (in addition to, not instead of, the grounding wire back to the main panel.)

An alternate possibility since you are clearly not a fan of pulling cable in conduit would be to choose direct burial, where you'd only need protective conduit sleeves at the ends, your trench would need to be 24" to the top of the cable, and you could easily benefit from the odd pricing that makes 2-2-2-4 mobile home feeder cable often cheaper than smaller wiring options.

One method to deal with the "house end connection" is to buy a large PVC box, (which has no holes) and PVC connectors designed to attach a conduit to that box when you drill the holes where you want them (allowing you to use a much smaller conduit through the wall, sized as a nipple at less than 24" long, which permits more fill percentage.) You could do the same thing with an LB and a reducing fitting glued into the back connector. In either case there is conduit all the way through the wall to another box or fitting inside the house, not what you have sketched out of Romex going through the wall.

Comment: Or #2 aluminum would also suffice, and may be more readily available since it's wider used, sometimes at almost the same price as #4.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a great answer. I'll price out the Al vs Cu wire. Definitely appreciate the suggestion to put smurf tube in the house so I can use the higher thermal limit of thwn wire.