Electrical issue pulling wires under driverway thru conduit
I have a short in our exterior lights which I have found which line was the issue and need to rerun the wires thru the conduit which goes under cement driveway. What is the best way to pull the wires to rerun back thru conduit?

Did you pull the old wires already? If not use them to pull the new wires.

Rerunning and running wire through conduit are the same process. If the conduit is damaged underground (rare, but less rare if not installed to code in the first place...) you might need to dig it up and repair it. Covered  (along with a bunch of other stuff irrelevant to just that part) in this answer: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/271910/18078

If you already pulled the wires out, you'll have to run a pull string.  You can often use a shop vac to pull a plastic bag through, with the string attached.
